# Match string unless starts and ends with character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regex in JavaScript to decide if a message gets deleted. I want to delete the message if it contains "string" anywhere, unless it's surrounded by colons.

- `string` - gets deleted
- `blah string` - gets deleted
- `:string blah` - gets deleted
- `:string: string` - gets deleted
- `thing :string:` - doesn't get deleted

I'm using JavaScript, and so far I'm using `message.match(/string/i)` to see if the message gets deleted. I've tried a negative lookahead, but I probably used it wrong.

EDIT: Sorry for not including this earlier, but `:blahstring:` and `:stringblah:` and `:blahstringblah:` should not be deleted as well.

Comment: Why does `thing :string:` not get deleted?

Comment: @guest271314 Because the word `string` is surrounded with colon

Comment: Try `/(?<!:(?=string:))string/i` if lookbehind is supported.

Comment: @Sparky Deleted

Comment: @LGSon What is the difference between `:string: string - gets deleted` and `thing :string: - doesn't get deleted`? Why is `:string:` not matched in the second case?

Comment: @guest271314 Not really sure, but it appears the OP want that if `string` occurs both with and w/o colon it should be deleted, but not if once with.

Comment: @UnknownUser I update answer

Comment: Concerning your edit: Is "bla" to be taken literally, or can it be any sequence of letters? Can it include spaces? Punctuation? It is not really that clear now...

Comment: @trincot Any arbitrary sequence, sorry.

Comment: But with an arbitrary sequence it is enough that the string starts and ends with a colon to make it acceptable, like ": this is a long sentence with string and it should be ok :". Should such a string ***not*** be deleted?

Comment: @trincot THat should be deleted. Spaces break it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some boundary cases where the colon appears only at one side of "string". Therefore I believe it is easier to remove all occurrences of ":string:" and only then look for a match of "string":

```js
function deleteIt(msg) {
    return /string/i.test(msg.replace(/:\w*string\w*(?=:)/ig, ":"));
}

console.log(deleteIt("this is :string ")); // true
console.log(deleteIt("this is string: ")); // true
console.log(deleteIt("string:string: ")); // true
console.log(deleteIt("this is :string: ")); // false
console.log(deleteIt("this is :blastring:stringbla:string: ")); // false
```

The last test in the above snippet is a special case. The colon is "shared" by a preceding and following "string". Depending on whether you want such "string" occurrences to be ignored or not, you may need to replace the look-ahead with a normal capture of the second colon.

#### Addendum

In your edit to the question, you say that ":blastring:" or ":stringbla:" should also not trigger a deletion.

So I added `\w*` twice in the regex above to align with that extra requirement.

If also punctuation or other non-alphabetical characters could be allowed between the colon and "string", like ":,-°string^0&:", just not white-space, then use `\S*` instead of `\w*`.

Comment: I saw your edit to the question, so I added `\w*` twice in the regex to align with that extra requirement. Let me know if that is what you need. If you intended to detect a *literal* "bla", then replace those `\w*` with `(bla)?`

Answer (score 4):

If lookbehind is supported you may use

```
/(?<!:(?=string:))string/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0bYjhy/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!:(?=string:))` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is `:` that is not immediately followed with `string:`
- `string` - a `string`

```js
var strs = ['string - gets deleted','blah string - gets deleted',':string blah - gets deleted',':string: string - gets deleted','thing :string: - doesnt get deleted'];
var rx = /(?<!:(?=string:))string/i;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Output:

```
string - gets deleted => true
blah string - gets deleted => true
:string blah - gets deleted => true
:string: string - gets deleted => true
thing :string: - doesnt get deleted => false
```

**A version without lookbehind**

It is based on a regex that matches `string` either without colons or with colons on both sides. If the matches contain at least one match with no colon at the start, the entry must be deleted.

```js
var strs = ['string - gets deleted','blah string - gets deleted',':string blah - gets deleted',':string: string - gets deleted','thing :string: - doesnt get deleted'];
var rx = /(?::(?=string:))?string/gi;
for (var s of strs) {
  var matches = s.match(rx);
  console.log(s, "=>", (matches.some(function (x) { return !/^:/.test(x); }) ));
}
```

Comment: I guess I accidentally clicked edit on this instead of my answer, whoever looks at this things please discard my edit.

Comment: Ah, and I was puzzled to see another regex in my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work with my test cases. :D

Comment: @UnknownUser It does, see the demo. Only the last one is `false`

Comment: @UnknownUser What test case does it not work with? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @UnknownUser Added a version without a lookbehind.

Comment: This is the perfect answer now. I added another test case though that I just realized, any way you could modify it? Thanks so much, sorry.

Comment: @UnknownUser Your edit does not change my approach, you just need to use the right pattern instead of `string`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I couldn't get it to work with `.*`. I was able to modify trincot's answer, though. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of positive lookbehind and negative lookahead:

```
(?<=^|[^:]|(:))string(?!\1)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ca1TTW/1

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in my tests: `^.*(?<!\:)string(?!\:).*$`

- `^` Match the start of the string
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `(?<!\:)` Match if the `:` suffix is missing
- `string` Match the word `string`
- `(?!\:)` Match if the suffix is missing
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `$` Match the end of the line

Comment: I love the explanation, it really helped clear some things up for me, but @blhsing's answer is the one that solved my problem.

Comment: @UnknownUser Also, If his answered solved the problem please mark it as the Answer to help people in the future.

Comment: I think this gives the wrong result for ":string" and for "string:".

Comment: @AdamH I would, but now stackoverflow makes you wait a while

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let s=[ "string",
        "blah string",
        ":string blah",
        ":string: string",
        "thing :string:",
        ":blahstring:",
        ":stringblah:",
        ":blahstringblah:",
      ];

let d=s.filter(x=> !x.match(/:.*string.*:/i) || x.match(/:.*string.*:.*string.*/i) || x.match(/.*string.*:.*string.*:/i));

console.log('Delete :', d);
console.log('Save   :', s.filter(x=>!d.includes(x)) );
```

We put to "delete list" `d` elementh which

- `!x.match(/:string:/i)` - not contains `:string:` or
- `x.match(/:.*string.*:.*string.*/i)` contains `:string:` and then `string` non surrounded by `:`
- `x.match(/.*string.*:.*string.*:/i)` same as above but vice-versa